# How to click the overlapping shapes in react konva?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva

I have the shapes (Rectangle, Ellipse and Polygon) that can overlap. I want to be able to select the inner shape inside the bigger one. If the bigger one is at the top, there is no way I can select the inner shape. I can't hover over it, click it or drag it. Is there any way to solve the issue?? If we look at the figma, if the shapes or whatever are overlapping we can double click and we are able to select the inner shape. Is there any similar way to do that in react konva??

Answer (score 1):

In Konva.Stage there is the [getAllIntersections](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Stage.html#getAllIntersections__anchor) method which will give a list of all of the shapes at any point on the stage. From here you could make UI to show the shapes and allow the user to select the specific shape to be transformed. The shape can then be dragged or sized as needed.

Comment: In order to use that I must provide the positions as an object {x:number,y:number}. How exactly is that useful to my situation?  I will only get the shapes that intersect at the given point. Whereas what I need is to find the shapes that are intersecting and put the smaller shape on top of the bigger one so that it can be dragged,hoverd and clicked.

Comment: You would set a click listener on the stage which has an event parameter and that has the x,y pos of the click. Then pass that into stage.getAllIntersections() and you get a list of the shapes at that point. What you do with the list is up to you and your ui coding.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't have a fill color for your shape or if it is transparent, you can set the **fillEnabled** to **false** which is true by default. This will make the overlapping shapes inside it selectable.

   ```
    <Rect
      fill={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}
      fillEnabled={false} />
   ```
2. Next if you have still want to drag the object with fill disabled, set the **shouldOverdrawWholeArea** to **true** in the transformer, this will fill whole transformer area with fake transparent shape to enable dragging from empty spaces.

   ```
   <Transformer
       ref={trRef}
       shouldOverdrawWholeArea={true} />
   ```

The above snippets are example from React, but it works for the JS implementation as well, using the above mentioned properties.